# Selenium Chromedriver suddenly not working : seesion not created exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My code, which used to work until yesterday, suddenly stopped working. I'd been running codes from jupyter notebook to auto-collect repeating data from a webpage. It is as follows (URL is changed to Google for privacy reasons):

```
# use selenium to start Chrome session to open a certain page 
dr = webdriver.Chrome()
dr.get("http://www.google.com")
```

The error message I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-84be89301b0d> in <module>()
      1 # use selenium to start Chrome session to open google. 
----> 2 dr = webdriver.Chrome()
      3 dr.get("http://www.google.com")

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, chrome_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path)
     65                 command_executor=ChromeRemoteConnection(
     66                     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url),
---> 67                 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     68         except:
     69             self.quit()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive)
     85         self.error_handler = ErrorHandler()
     86         self.start_client()
---> 87         self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
     88         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
     89         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
    139             desired_capabilities['firefox_profile'] = browser_profile.encoded
    140         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, {
--> 141             'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
    142         })
    143         self.session_id = response['sessionId']

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    199         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    200         if response:
--> 201             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    202             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    203                 response.get('value', None))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    179         elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException and 'alert' in value:
    180             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].get('text'))
--> 181         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    182 
    183     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"7600.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
```

I really have no idea how to solve this and why I'm suddenly getting this message.

Comment: Have you checked for changes in your test environment?  Have you tried reinstalling the driver?

Comment: @BreaksSoftware I tried uninstalling and re-installing selenium but it's no use. And as far as I know no changes were made on my test environment.

Comment: Please download new chrome driver and use the same.. recently i got the same issue..

Comment: @PotnuruRavi you mean chromedriver 2.24 from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads?

Comment: this is the link http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/

Comment: we'll get same version but the new one is working like charm

Comment: @PotnuruRavi Thanks. I downloaded the mac64 version but I'm getting WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
instead. Any ideas?

Comment: @PotnuruRavi I tried editing path with sudo vi etc/paths ... but not working. Sorry I keep bugging you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126625/discussion-between-potnuru-ravi-and-bossam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download again new chrome driver from below link and use the same

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/

Comment: you've been most helpful Thanks mate